# Replace subquery with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

flats

```
   id - primary key
   title - text
```

flats_reservations

```
   id - primary key
   flat_id - foreign key to Flats(id)
   creator_id - foreign key to users(id)
   is_reserved - boolean
   created_at - current_timestamp
```

If flats_reservations has these rows

```
id=1, flat_id=12, creator_id=5, is_reserved=1, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:00
id=2, flat_id=12, creator_id=5, is_reserved=0, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:05
id=3, flat_id=12, creator_id=4, is_reserved=1, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:10
```

Then **only** user with id=4 can remove reservation (e.g. insert following row (**is_reserved=0**)

```
id=4, flat_id=12, creator_id=4, is_reserved=0, created_at=2016-10-10 00:00:10
```

No other user can make this.

How can I select list of all flats with their current (e.g. latest) reservation status?

Simple, but not effective way - for every flat

```
select is_reserved from flat_reservations where flat_id={id} order by created_at desc limit 1
```

This can be done with subquery too

```
select flats.id, flats.title, (select is_reserved from flat_reservations where flat_id=flats.id order by created_at desc limit 1) as is_reserved from flats;
```

But how can I make this more effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially your query:

```
select f.id, f.title,
       (select is_reserved
        from flat_reservations fr
        where fr.flat_id = f.id
        order by fr.created_at desc
        limit 1
       ) as is_reserved
from flats f;
```

This is a fine way to do what you want.  You want an index on `flat_reservations(flat_id, created_at, is_reserved)` if performance is an issue.